# Crash of the visual basic 6 IDE just before loading the project ends; only when source safe is active

Tags: vb6, visual-sourcesafe

I am at my wits end with this one.
I have a vb6 project that edits, compiles and runs well as long as I do not try to synchronize its files with the visual source safe 6.0d database at loading. I tried removing the .scc files, I tried filling the working folder from the database and vice versa, all to no avail.

The problem started when I tried to add a new class module to the project, for which VB6 complained that the .vbp project file should be checked out first. Somewhere after that I got an error and now this is the result.

What file could be the culprit in such a way that it does not interfere with 'source safe-less'  execution, but causes a crash when I do use it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been unable to reliably reproduce the error, but it seems to happen when the number of files in the project reaches a certain level. A workaround I found is to disable sourcecontrol before loading the project and loading the sourcecontrol AddIn after all files are present in the IDE.

Comment: I recently found the comfort of *not* loading Source Control plug-in at all. I'm using VSS explorer now (trying to migrate to TFS) and the IDE is much more stable and somewhat faster. Most convenient thing is that I can now edit read-only files at run-time, checking them out later. More goodness, MZ-Tools can be configured to use a shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+S at my place) to save a modified file at run-time. This alone saves hours in project restart time!